# Append ID of button to input value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append the `id` of a button to an `input` value on button click?

Example input (buttons pressed):

`#en` `#de` `#fr` `#it` `#es`

Example output:

`<input name="langs" value="en,de,fr,it,es,">`

This is what I have, but it's not working:

```
$(".lang-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("input[name=languages]").val() += $(this).attr("id") . ",";
});
```

I would then like to be able to re-adjust the `input`value, removing the `id`, when the button is pressed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close, `.val()` takes the value as a param:

```
$(".lang-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var id = this.id,
        currentValue = $("input[name=languages]").val();

    //Check for existing
    if (currentValue.indexOf(id) > -1) {
        //remove it
        currentValue = currentValue.replace(id + ",", "");
        $("input[name=languages]").val(currentValue);
    } else {
        $("input[name=languages]").val(currentValue + id + ",");
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9L76d0sr/

Comment: Should `this.id,` be something like `$(this).id;` as I cannot get this code working? A jsfiddle or the suchlike would be much appreciated.

Comment: @mpdc -- Nope, `this` refers to the native DOM element.

Comment: Thank you. Mine works, except from removing the values when the button is pressed again. Identical code too. Hmm...

Comment: @mpdc -- I made an edit to fix that, the line `currentValue = currentValue.replace(id + ",", "");`

Comment: Phenomenal, must have missed that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have radio buttons, you could see if there are checked or not:  document.getElementById("X").checked = true;

 Then you can append them as you want in your input field